# Heroku Won't Let Bootstrap Collapse Menu Open When Clicked Works in Local Host

Tags: heroku, video, menu, navigation

My app has a collapsable Bootstrap menu that works in local host but Heroku doesn't let it get clicked- funny thing it worked for 10 minutes when my Heroku app first deployed and then never worked after that. I thought it was too much data so I compressed my background video file and put it back and now the video file doesn't show either. Why is Heroku not letting the collapse menu work? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It actually WAS a Bootstrap security flaw. The answer was to change the gem listing from a hard-lined version request to a the traditional Tilda: bootstrap < 4.1.2 into bootstrap ~> 4.1.2. And yes, the compressed video now works- kept mp4 format and chopped it to be a smaller file in iMovie. My images won't show in model instances so I reduced size and it seems to be a different issue- working on pagination if possibly a page load issue for Heroku.